# Regular expression - repeat groups

Tags: php, regex

I have text:

```
<b>Title1:</b><br/><b>Title2:</b> Value1<br/><b>Title3:</b> Value2<br/><b>Title4:</b> Value3<br/>Value4<b>Title5:</b> Value5<br/>
```

What regex to get:

```
[0] => <b>Title1:</b><br/>
[1] => <b>Title2:</b> Value1<br/>
[2] => <b>Title3:</b> Value2<br/>
[3] => <b>Title4:</b> Value3<br/>Value4
[4] => <b>Title5:</b> Value5<br/>
```

My variant not working:
`<b>(.*?)</b>(.*?)`

Comment: If you are processing HTML, then using a DOM parser would probably be a better idea.

Comment: Ooooh - is it time for *[that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)* answer again?

Comment: H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ

Comment: @CD001 No it's not. [It's only broken code, not life and death.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#comment1612336_1732454)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @CD001 C̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `preg_split()` with a lookahead:

```
<?php
$split = preg_split( '/(?=<b>Title\d+:)/', '<b>Title1:</b><br/><b>Title2:</b> Value1<br/><b>Title3:</b> Value2<br/><b>Title4:</b> Value3<br/>Value4<b>Title5:</b> Value5<br/>' );
array_shift( $split );
var_dump( $split );
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "<b>Title1:</b><br/>"
  [1]=>
  string(26) "<b>Title2:</b> Value1<br/>"
  [2]=>
  string(26) "<b>Title3:</b> Value2<br/>"
  [3]=>
  string(32) "<b>Title4:</b> Value3<br/>Value4"
  [4]=>
  string(26) "<b>Title5:</b> Value5<br/>"
}
```

---

Your regex was close, you need:

```
<b>(.*?)<\/b>(.*?)(?=<b>|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/dk67IK/1

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that instead of Title any text
But your regular work! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

A resource like this can be very useful in troubleshooting regex: https://regex101.com/

Looks like you are missing an escape character in `<b>(.*?)</b>(.*?)`

`<b>(.*?)<\/b>(.*?)` should stop an error from being thrown for that current regex and get you close to the result, you'll need to work with it a bit more to get the exact results you want though.

`<b>(.*?)<\/b>(.*?)<br\/>` should be a bit closer I think as it looks like you want to include the break tags.